# Download a 2 GB file using PHP

Tags: php

I have written a PHP page for downloading files from the server.  The name of the file is passed as a GET variable in the URL, and then the following code serves up the file for download:

```
$filepath = "/path/to/files";
$filename = $_GET['id'];

if( ! file_exists($filepath . "/" . $filename) )
{
    header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
    @session_destroy();
    exit(0);
}

$cmd = '/usr/bin/stat -c "%s" ' . $filepath . "/" . $filename;
$out = array();
$ret = 0;

exec( $cmd, $out, $ret );

header('Content-type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Length: ' . $out[0]);
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');

readfile($filepath . "/" . $filename);
```

NOTE: I am using the exec() call because most of the files are large (>2GB) and the larger files caused the filesize() and stat() functions to fail.

Anyway, this code works perfectly for almost all of the files.  However, when a file is *exactly* 2 GB in size (2147483648 bytes), no headers are sent and the browser attempts to download the PHP page itself, which results in a empty file being saved called download.php.

Here's what happened when I tested this with curl:

Test #1: Get a 1 GB file called bigfile1:

```
$ curl -v http://<SERVER>/download.php?id=bigfile1
* About to connect() to <SERVER> port 80 (#0)
*   Trying <IP_ADDRESS>... connected
* Connected to <SERVER> (<IP_ADDRESS>) port 80 (#0)
> GET /download.php?id=bigfile1 HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.18.2 (i486-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.18.2 OpenSSL/0.9.8g zlib/1.2.3.3 libidn/1.8 libssh2/0.18
> Host: <SERVER>
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Tue, 21 Jun 2011 19:10:06 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.2.4 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.4 OpenSSL/0.9.8c PHP/5.3.0
< X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.0
< Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=382769731f5e3782e3c1e3e14fc8ae71; path=/
< Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
< Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
< Pragma: no-cache
< Content-Length: 1073741824
< Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="bigfile1"
< Content-Type: application/octet-stream
<
* Connection #0 to host <SERVER> left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

Test #2: Get a 2 GB file called bigfile2

```
$ curl -v http://<SERVER>/download.php?id=bigfile2
* About to connect() to <SERVER> port 80 (#0)
*   Trying <IP_ADDRESS>... connected
* Connected to <SERVER> (<IP_ADDRESS>) port 80 (#0)
> GET /download.php?id=bigfile2 HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.18.2 (i486-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.18.2 OpenSSL/0.9.8g zlib/1.2.3.3 libidn/1.8 libssh2/0.18
> Host: <SERVER>
> Accept: */*
>
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host <SERVER> left intact
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
* Closing connection #0
```

I have created test files which are 1 GB, 2 GB, 3 GB, 4 GB, and 5 GB in size.  The 2 GB file is the only one that causes this behavior, but it happens consistently, and it seems to happen regardless of the client browser or OS.  The server is running Debian GNU/Linux 4.0, Apache 2.2.4, and PHP 5.3.0.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Is it the `readfile` or `exec` that causes the problem? Comment them out one-by-one to check.

Comment: What is your 'PHP_INT_MAX' output?  And/or, is this a 64 or 32 bit host (OS type is irrelevant, I mean the actual hardware type here)?

Comment: Put a call to `error_log()` on every other line to find out exactly what the code path is for the 2G file.  Could it just be that the file doesn't exist and your script exits after `session_destroy()`?

Comment: --Also - the PHP manual suggests using `sprintf("%u", filesize($file))` for 32 bit platforms - have you tried that?

Comment: I tried using sprintf() but the problem is that the embedded call to filesize() fails.  Using exec() to call the stat command in the underlying OS was the best idea I could come up with off the top of my head.

Comment: The host is a 32-bit Intel box.  The file exists and is readable.  It's on an NFS volume shared from another server, but that doesn't seem to be the problem.  Everything works correctly in the OS, and it's only the 2 GB file that's causing an issue in PHP.

Comment: @Dave: Not really an answer, but intuitively `readfile` and/or `stat` may be failing at this size because it just so happens to be the max int size (PHP_INT_MAX=2147483647) + 1 on a 32 bit platform.  You aren't casting the file size, and PHP should automatically cast it to a double, so I'm not sure yet what's going on myself.

Comment: @konforce: it looks like `readfile()` is causing the problem.  The `exec()` call gets the file size like it should.  I added calls to `ob_clean()` and `flush()` after the headers, and now the browser gets the correct file name and size, but it still downloads an empty file.  What's interesting is that the response size is correct in the access log:

`"GET /download.php?id=bigfile2 HTTP/1.1" 200 2147483648`

Comment: I ended up installing mod_sendfile and using the X-Sendfile header to solve this problem (see the solution posted by konforce, below).  I was hoping to find a purely PHP solution, but I don't think it's possible on my 32-bit platform.  I'm going to file a PHP bug report and see what happens.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a 64-bit installation, I had no problems with the file size you mentioned using PHP 5.3.6. A 32-bit installation gave me:

```
failed to open stream: Value too large for defined data type
```

But that said, I would not even use `readfile`. Instead:

```
header("X-Sendfile: $filepath/$filename");
```

It requires mod_xsendfile be installed and configured.

Comment: I saw mod_xsendfile mentioned in another post.  Perhaps I'll give that a try.  Thanks.

Comment: X-Sendfile solved the problem (and mod_xsendfile was incredibly easy to install and configure).  Thanks for the information!

Answer (score 1):

I put that in a comment, but the formatting doesn't help, so I'll post this as an answer too, although it does not answer your question. What would happen if an attacker visits this URL?

`http://yourserver.com/download.php?id=../../../../etc/passwd`

**Watch out** for directory traversals in your `id` GET variable.

```
$realfile = realpath($filepath .'/'. $filename);
if (substr($realfile, strlen($filepath)) == $filepath && file_exists($realfile))
{
  do_the_download();
} else {
  die('file not found (or you are a bad person)');
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Actually, what I do in this case is get a list of the files in the directory, and then check the value of `$_GET['id']` against the list.  If it contains anything other than a filename in the list, then the script throws an error.

Comment: Well, depending on the number of files in that directory that may be a hit in performance, but yes, at least you are protected :)